# Express Mounting Point

Tags: node.js, express

So i have been going back and forth on this topic, and not very clear on it. I am currently working on a app where i am trying to set my path as `localhost:8000/app`

Right now if i hit localhost:8000, it renders the page but on localhost:8000/app its says the url is not recognized

As far as my code set up, i have the routes directory as follow

```
routes
  app
    index.js
```

I have my router middleware in config.json file set to

```
"router": {
            "module": {
                "arguments": [{ "directory": "path:./routes" }]
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you using any library?

Comment: @Qualcuno No library

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a template library ?

Because it may look for a file with the right extension.

Example:
If you're using jade, it will look for .jade file

Comment: yes i am using 'dust' as templating library but how does that affect process?

Comment: On /app, dust will search for app/index.dust but it wont find the file

Comment: i dont believe your templating structure needs to simulate the routing path, but i did figure out the issue instead of './routes' it should have been './routes/'

Answer (score 0):

Okay figured out where the fault was under my config.json i need to add '/' after './routes'

```
"router": {
            "module": {
                "arguments": [{ "directory": "path:./routes/" }]
            }
        }
```

Hence it was not recognizing the route structure